# How to we consume traditional Webservice from .NET 6 API using client and server authentication and using proxy class from WSDL

Tags: c#, soap, .net-6.0

I have .Net 6 API and have a use case to consume SOAP service. I have created proxy class from the WSDL file and connect using client/server certificate authentication.
In .net framework, we can add web config behaviour and end point to do this but in .Net 6 its not working.
Anyone has any idea on how to do this?